# Fixing boot issue on Windows XP Pro 32 bit

Tags: boot, windows-xp

Our lab has an old computer (some German brand) with proprietary software. No cd or floppy drive. No recovery cd as far as I'm aware. It came included with an extremely expensive machine that it runs. Unfortunately, the computer part of the setup is now having boot issues.

The company never allowed users to install the software; the only way to use it was to buy a computer from them with the software preinstalled. The setup is now old enough that it is no longer under warranty, and the company does not have old computers that they can sell us. Our only option with them is to do a full hardware upgrade of the machine, which would then include a new computer with a newer version of the software that works with the upgrade. This would be prohibitively expensive for us. So our only option is finding a way to fix the computer ourselves.

**Symptoms**

The computer will start the boot process and show the Windows XP Professional logo with the green scrolling thing below. The screen will then go blank and nothing will happen. The auto-restart appears to be disabled. In the boot options, I've tried loading old restore points without any luck. Attempting to boot into safe mode or the recovery console also get me nowhere (as in they don't get me to a point where I can even type commands). The only other things that seem to happen is a text list of system files loading, with the last one being "mup.sys" before freezing, or a BSOD with a 0x7b error.

**Things I've Done**

I did try plugging the hard drive into another computer I have. All different hardware, including mouse, keyboard, monitor, cables. Exact same symptoms, except that here it reboots after showing the loading screen, rather than going blank.

I can plug the hard drive into one of the spare sata slots in my linux machine, mount it, and access the files perfectly fine. This seems to rule out a physical issue with the hard drive itself.

I've tried creating a virtual image of the hard drive with VirtualBox's `createrawvmdk` command and loading it up in VirtualBox. Works even less well here, no matter how much I try to tune the settings.

I extracted the virtual hard drive image from Microsoft's XP mode thing for Windows 7+, and was able to successfully install that in VirtualBox, so I do have a clean XP install running fine there. I then used VirtualBox to create a hard drive link to the problematic hard drive. I can now successfully load the clean XP build, and have the problematic one show up as a second drive.

From the clean XP build, I loaded up command prompt and ran chkdsk on the drive with the bad system. It seemed to go fine, with the only issue being detected and fixed was the uppercase file, which does not appear to be related to booting at all.

I found an XP recovery iso, booted from it in VirtualBox, and used it to get into recovery mode. From there, I ran chkdsk which apparently found one unspecified issue and fixed it. Running chkdsk again came back clean.

**Partial Workaround**

Since I can access the files just fine, I copied all of the program and user files related to the software I could find. I then installed them into a Windows 10 virtual machine. With some trial and error, I was able to get it to the point that it could run the machine.

The problem is that it is not 100% functional. Mainly, simulations do not seem to be accessible in the software. This does not affect operation of the machine, but is a very useful tool for when designing and testing workflows. There is another small issue, but it is easily worked around, as long as it doesn't start doing anything unexpected.

I also tried copying the files into the working XP vm I have, and it seems to work slightly less well.

It's possible that while I have found all the program files, there might be some underlying system or registry changes associated with software that a file search cannot find.

Maybe there is a chance that running it in Windows 10 outside of a vm will fix these issues, but it's not something I can try at the moment.

**Ideal Solution**

Get the original system up and running again. At least long enough for me to use the proper tools to make a proper virtual hard drive image that can be backed up and run in virtual machines. I've done this before for another very old system and it worked great. However, in that case, the computer was old, but still functioning.

**Help**
Any thoughts on how I can go about finding the issue and fixing it? I don't think it would be anything with MBR, given that I can get to the loading screen. I suspect it must be an issue with a system file or driver. The computer is not connected to any network, so no Windows updates that could have affected it, and the only way a virus could have gotten on it would be through a usb drive.

Comment: Is there a reason you just don't back up and clean reinstall XP?

Comment: I does make me wonder why no-one thought to clone it while it was still working, precisely in case of this eventuality. Things like Acronis have been able to do 'universal restore' to dissimilar hardware for over a decade. In fact, it *might* still be worth a go. Once you've got a full, preserved backup, you can mess with copies to your heart's content.

Comment: What is "the machine" and how is it attached? Given the likely age of the hardware id focus on getting the software running on a different machine. If thats really impossible id try to eliminate any hardware issues (peripherals / specific ports on the baseunit etc). Do you have a ntbtlog.txt in Windows dir (boot log) - might have clues? Have you extracted the Event Logs - XP used a wierd binary format but theres scripts online to decode them. Lastly mup.sys is probably the last device that loaded successfully - you should be more interested in the device that loads after it.

Comment: @Tetsujin My lab group is all biologists; I'm the only one with a tech background. Apparently the issue started a while ago and it was getting worse over time, but I haven't used it personally in over a year, and no one told me. If I had known it was starting to have issues earlier, I would have cloned it with one of those tools while I still could.

Comment: @MisterSmith The only connection is an ethernet port, which is why I can run it using a different computer I have with Windows 10 in a vm. The problem is that some functionality is missing, and I'm not sure if it's because I'm missing something important that was installed or altered by the software when the company installed it, or if it's because I'm running in a vm.

Comment: @MisterSmith There is no ntbtlog.txt in the Windows dir. The .evt log files appear to have last been updated when the computer last worked. A file search by modification date in linux shows similarly named .log files in the same folder as the event logs that were modified during the startup, but they are also in a binary format. I also suspected as much with the mup.sys, but checked it anyway using `diff` in linux; it's exactly the same as the one in the XP Mode download

Comment: @MisterSmith Randomly perusing through the drivers folder, I see stuff for both an Intel 82574L ethernet controller and a Siemens CP 1616 profinet controller... so it might not just be a regular old ethernet port after all

Comment: Given its age i would assume hardware failure is most likely - but you need to narrow down what. Do you have access to a spare harddisk / different XP era PC? Can you open the PC and confirm what hardwares inside? I expect the PC is pretty standard except for that Siemens card and its software/config? Given the controllers age i doubt you will be able to virtualise it. The XP driver will be expecting physical access to that card, and the XP era drivers for your hardware will not work in modern Windows. I'm assuming your missing features relates to some device driver thats not loaded?